# VLCJ player not playing RTSP Stream

Tags: video, client, video-streaming, vlcj

I have Two files with vlcj.
 1. RTSP Server => which streams(Sout) a local movie

```
    String options = formatRtspStream("A.B.C.D", 1025, "demo");
    System.out.println("Streaming '" + media + "' to '" + options + "'");
    mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(media,
        options);
```

run the server to start streaming from 1st vlc instance(Server).

2. RTSP Client => to play the stream in 2nd vlc instance(Client)

   ```
   String mrl = new RtspMrl().host("A.B.C.D").port(1025).path("/demo").value();
   mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(mrl,options);
   ```

but when i run the client, my player don't play the stream and its just a blank screen.

and when i use command line "vlc RTSP://A.B.C.D/1025/demo" => it plays the stream.

i don't know why it doesn't play with vlcj client and plays nicely using direct vlc. 
Can anybody guide what could be the problem?

Comment: Facing the same problem: "open of `rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.237:88/video' failed", followed by messages telling me VLC couldn't open the RLM.

Comment: Could you explain how you start your server, if with using vlcj please add the code it may be related to that. Can you change the line in step 2 with this: 
**mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("RTSP://A.B.C.D/1025/demo");**